# Java script drop down menu access Watir-web driver

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am having problems trying to access some a link in a drop down menu In a web site. When you put your cursor over the button, as shown in the first picture, the menu drops down. Below that is a picture of the webpage script. What i want to do is click the search specifications button inn the drop down menu. 
the like of code would go something like this :

```
e.frame(:name => "content").frame(:name => "main").a(:index => 0).click.a(:index => 10).click
```

However, that is not a valid peace of code, i just don't know the right way of doing it.

[image]

[image]

```
< e.frame(:name => "content").frame(:name => "main")
=> #<Watir::Frame:0x7f74b4d4 located=false selector={:name=>"main"}>
irb(main):064:0> my_frame.a(:text => 'Operations').click
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:text
=>"Operations", :tag_name=>"a"}
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir
-webdriver/elements/element.rb:365:in `assert_exists'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir
-webdriver/elements/element.rb:95:in `click'
        from (irb):64
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):065:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menu does not appear to be in the HTML part that you posted. It is likely further down in the HTML.

Instead of trying to locate by index, which can easily change, you could locate by text. Try:

```
my_frame = e.frame(:name => "content").frame(:name => "main")
my_frame.a(:text => 'Operations').click
my_frame.a(:text => 'Search Specifications').click
```

This assumes that the 'Search Specifications' link is also in the same frame as the 'Operations' link.

Comment: I tried this code but it does not work. Even the first part does not work. It says unable to locate element, using.... Also, I cant get it to work using the same methodology but indexes

Comment: my_frame = e.frame(:name => "content").frame(:name => "main")
 my_frame.a(:index => 0).click
 my_frame.a(:index => any index number they all dont work).click

Comment: Another this think that came to mined, is that you don't click the for the menu to come down all you have to do it hold your mouse over it.

Comment: When you say 'the first part does not work'... are you talking about you cannot even access the frame? Which frame can it not locate? The first one or the second?

Comment: Sorry I guess i should have said the 2nd line of code does not work.

Comment: Can you post the exception that occurs? The second line failing could be a result of either frame or the link not being located. Because no 'action' occurs in the first line, it does not actually attempt to locate the frame until the second line.

Comment: If you do a `my_frame.links.each{ |x| puts x.text }` (ie output the text of all links) what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myframe.a(:text, 'Operations').fire_event 'mouseover'
myframe.a(:text, 'Search Specifications').click
```

Not sure if this is perfect, but the idea is that you make the link in the drop down menu present after you select the drop down. Play around with other elements. The fire_event method is the best way I know to make the drop down menu present.